# Why won't ENUMs work in subqueries in H2?

Tags: java, sql, enums, subquery, h2

With the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE FOOD (
  SERIAL_NUMBER BIGINT,
  FOOD_TYPE ENUM('FRUIT','VEGGIE','MEAT')
);
```

and the following data:

```
INSERT INTO FOOD(SERIAL_NUMBER, FOOD_TYPE)
VALUES(12345, 'FRUIT');
```

I'm trying to execute the below query in H2:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
  SELECT * FROM FOOD WHERE FOOD_TYPE <> 'MEAT'
)
```

And I'm getting the below error:

```
Column "MEAT" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT count(*) from ( 
SELECT * FROM FOOD WHERE FOOD_TYPE <> 'MEAT' 
) [42122-197]
```

Without the `WHERE` clause or with filtering on `SERIAL_NUMBER` instead of `FOOD_TYPE`, the query runs fine and returns *'1'*. Is there something about ENUMs in subqueries that H2 cannot handle?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if u use Table contain your types than using enum.
Example from sqlit:

```
CREATE TABLE Price (
  PriceId INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  Name    VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL,
  Type    CHAR(1)       NOT NULL DEFAULT ('M') REFERENCES PriceType(Type)
);

CREATE TABLE PriceType (
  Type    CHAR(1)       PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  Seq     INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO PriceType(Type, Seq) VALUES ('M',1);
INSERT INTO PriceType(Type, Seq) VALUES ('R',2);
INSERT INTO PriceType(Type, Seq) VALUES ('H',3);
```